# Xlookup to find latest data entry through multiple sheets in 1 workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook that contains 3 separate sheets that contain data from the years 2020, 2021, and 2022 (each are labelled only as the year).
I need to use xlookup to search for the latest value (usually a text string) within the column 'E'. So far I've made it search through the previous sheet (the year before) but there's no data in sheet 2021- how can I make it search through 2020 if there is no data in 2021?

My current formula for sheet '2022' is this:

```
=IFERROR(MAX($C:$C)-XLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2,1/(E10:E1000<>""),E10:E1000),E10:E1000,$C10:$C1000),XLOOKUP(E4,'2021'!4:4,'2021'!7:7))
```

To explain the formula, it looks for a value within column 'E', once it finds the latest value, it will take the associated data (a meter length) and subtract it from the furthest (latest) meter length. I.e if the last check was done at 10m, but the latest travelled distance is 30m, it will calculate that the last check was done 20m ago (30m - 10m). If that makes sense.

I tried using '&' but it gave me both of the latest values from 2020 and 2021 (which is expected).

TL;DR
Need a formula that searches for the latest value (usually text string) starting from sheet '2022' then goes through '2021' then '2020' until it find the latest value within column 'E'

**If a copy of my excel workbook is needed, I would be more than happy to send over a modified copy.**

Comment: Will give this a go with info you've provided - if we don't come right you can share a onedrive link but would need to ensure relevant info within linked workbook reflecting in Q too for benefit of future users should link break/become inaccesible at some pt...

Answer (score 1):

Nested iferror statements should do the trick --

You can either replicate what you did in sheet 2021 4:4/7:7 in sheet 2020, or perform the same lookup procedure as you've performed in Sheet 2022 (if appropriate/same format & layout etc.).

Here's an example of a nested iferror function that comprises the same lookup approach you adopted in Sheet '2022' across all 3 yrs, which you can modify as req. (e.g. should 2020-2021 have a different layout or if you're able to replicate 4:4/7:7 in sheet 2020 as well).

```
=IFERROR(MAX($C:$C)-XLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2, 1 / (E10:E1000 <>""), E10:E1000), E10:E1000, $C10:$C1000),
         IFERROR(MAX('2021'!C:C)-XLOOKUP( LOOKUP(2, 1/('2021'!E10:E1000<>""),  '2021'!E10:E1000), '2021'!E10:E1000,'2021'!C10:C1000),
                 IFERROR(MAX('2020'!C:C)-XLOOKUP( LOOKUP( 2,1/('2020'!E10:E1000<>""), '2020'!E10:E1000), '2020'!E10:E1000, '2020'!C10:C1000),
                         "there is simply no data!")))
```

[image: Nested iferror]